# PublishManager method WaitFor() always returns FALSE on Sitecore 7.2

Tags: publishing

I'm using the `PublishManager.Republish(...)` to programmatically perform a full republish in a few Sitecore instances.

Since I need this operation to be synchronous, I'm calling the `PublishManager.WaitFor(handle)` method right after the previous one.

It works like a charm on Sitecore 8x and 9x.

But I can't understand why the waitFor is always returning `false` on my Sitecore 72 instance.

Did anyone face the same situation? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: 
I'm using the types and methods present in Sitecore 7.2.151021 - Sitecore.Kernel.dll.

The handle returned by the Publish method is not null I can confirm here:

[image]

And I can confirm that the republish itself is being executed by seeing the newly created items on web database after a few seconds.

Comment: You mean you're using the Publishing Service?   If so, that is only supported on 8.x and above. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/545289

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm actually using the types and methods present in Sitecore.Kernel.7.2.151021, such as Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.Republish ()and then Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.WaitFor().

Comment: @HugoSantos the issue is because the handle may be null. In the Sitecore 7.2 Kernel, it actually fetch the job based on the `handle`. So, the reason why it may return false is either the handle is null or when getting the job, it is being returned as null

Comment: @HishaamNamooya that was my first reflex too, but I can debug this code and the handle is not null. My point here is: Why the JobManager.GetJob(handle) would return null? It does not make sense to me and that's what I'm trying to figure out... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PublishManager` in Sitecore 7.2 uses `PublishStrategy` mechanisms for publishing. It was deprecated in newer Sitecore versions.

`PublishManager.Republish` in the background calls its own `Publish` method with `PublishMode.Full` mode which then calls `Publish` method on `PublishManager.PublishStrategy`.

In not-scaled environment, with **Event Queues** disabled, default publish strategy is used, and standard job is added to `JobsManager`.

But when `Settings.EnableEventQueues` value is `true`, `PublishManager.PublishStrategy` property returns an object of `RemotePublishStrategy` type, which uses `DistributedPublishingManager.QueuePublish` and it doesn't use `JobsManager` but use `StartPublishingRemoteEvent` and the handle which is returned is a handle of that event, not a handle of a job queued in `JobsManager`.

One setting `Settings.EnableEventQueues` changes everything. Check your `showconfig.aspx` for the **EventQueue.Enabled** setting and if it's `true`, that's your answer.

Comment: I can confirm that I have the EnableEventQueues  = true. Thanks a lot Marek. So that means that if you are using event queues there is no way you can force sync behavior when calling the republish instead of an async?

Comment: I cannot tell this for sure as it's been ages since I last worked with 7.2. From what I see, there is no option with `PublishManager` directly, but you could try using `new Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher(options).Publish();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug on the Sitecore 7.2 version.

By using DotPeek I can see that the way Sitecore handle the `.WaitFor()` method is completely different from Sitecore 7.x to later versions.

On Sitecore 7.2 it uses the `JobManager.GetJob(handle)` to check the state of the republish.

The issue here is that after I call `PublishManager.Republish(...)` there aren't any job on the JobManager.

Yeah, exactly.

`JobManager.GetJobs()` is returning an empty array.

That's why the `PublishManager.WaitFor()` is always returning false.

Comment: Don't you use some RemotePublishingStrategy or other non-default implementation? I didn't debug the code but from what I can see, default publishing strategy calls JobManager.Start which adds new job to the `_jobs` list

Comment: Nops, I'm calling straight *PublishManager.Republish()* passing the master database and English language as parameter. And not only that but the publishing itself is working like a charm. It's the *PublishManager.WaitFor()* that is not doing its job properly. Thanks Marek!

Comment: Yes, but `PublishManager.Republish` calls `PublishManager.PublishStrategy.Publish(options, clientLanguage);`. And if `Settings.EnableEventQueues` value is `true`, `RemotePublishStrategy` is used instead of the default `PublishStrategy`. And it uses `DistributedPublishingManager.QueuePublish` which queues  `StartPublishingRemoteEvent` instead of using `JobManager`. One setting `Settings.EnableEventQueues` changes everything :)